# twitteR throws Forbidden error after entering twitter API PIN

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am trying to analyze some tweets using R and twitteR package. The handshake and registration code seems to work properly and I get the authorization link from R. However, when I enter the PIN obtained from https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize I get a "Forbidden Error." Any help is appreciated.

The Code:

```
TwitterOAuth<-function(){
  reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
  accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
  authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
  consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
  options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package =  "RCurl")))
  twitCred$handshake()
  registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
}
```

The Response:

> TwitterOAuth()
>   To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
>   http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=X0AwET4FXBC7YRIWWN3iF61WFNE1DjxbfibqtfFjgcc
>   
> When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: 1998913
>   
> Error: Forbidden

My sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Turkish_Turkey.1254  LC_CTYPE=Turkish_Turkey.1254    LC_MONETARY=Turkish_Turkey.1254
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Turkish_Turkey.1254

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.7  rjson_0.2.13   ROAuth_0.9.3   digest_0.6.4   RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2

Answer (score 24):

Change your access URL from http to https.

Comment: This solved it for me.  @user3265306 if you're still around and this works of you, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: I worked for me too. Thanks @Martin! Please @user3265306 mark that as an answer!

Answer (score 7):

You can follow this step (don't forget, valid URL is use https):

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "Mjn6tdsadsadkasdklad2SV1l"
consumerSecret <- "58Z7Eldsdfaslkf;asldsaoeorjkfksaVCQtvri"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

After you run this code you will see in R console message like this :

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=scmVODruosvz6Tdsdadadasdsa
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:
```

Just paste the link to your browser then authorize app, last one you will get the PIN code, just copy and paste the PIN code to your R console.

```
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

R console will show TRUE if you success.

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
userTimeline(user, n=20, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE)
```

Comment: When i use https in the url i am getting a ` Error in strsplit(response, "&") : non-character argument ` error

Answer (score 3):

Based on this blog: http://thinktostart.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/twitter-authentification-with-r/

```
library(RCurl)
# Set SSL certs globally
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

require(twitteR)
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

consumerKey <- "yourconsumerkey"

consumerSecret <- "yourconsumersecret"

twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)

twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))

registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "Error: forbidden" response and haven't resolved it today (although I did previously).

My R script for my Windows 8.1 system also includes this line:

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")

I found this line online with the comment to it, "this is a necessary step for Windows"

About three days ago I successfully reached Twitter after entering the online PIN number, but today I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies may be the problem: what appears to be the same thing happened to me, which was fixed when I  followed the link given by `twitcred$handshake()` in a different browser; i.e., I had been trying in Safari, but then gave it a try once in Chrome and the PIN that I received in Chrome was accepted without a problem in R.